# Извлечь текст между сиволами

Tags: php

Есть такая строка:

```
....код подтверждения: <b>XXXXX</b> .
```

Мне нужно получить текст который идет после  `:` и до точки.

Этот текст всегда внутри `<b></b>`

Но тегов `<b>` в строке может быть несколько.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в составлении регулярки.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zWvwOb/1